# Date Validation for Birth Date, Joining Date and Leaving Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, date, datepicker

I have three textboxes for `BirthDate`, `JoiningDate` & `LeavingDate`.

Now what I want is:-

1. `Joining date` and `Leaving date` should not be greater than `Birthdate`
2. `Leaving Date` should not be greater than `Joining Date` and `BirthDate`

I have used the DatePicker.

Here is the JS code:-

```
$(function () {
        $("[id$=mainContent_txtdateofbirth], [id$=mainContent_txtdoj], [id$=mainContent_txtdol]").datepicker({
            textboxImageOnly: true,
            textboxImage: 'images/calendar.png',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy / mm / dd",
            yearRange: "-40:+0",
            maxDate: new Date(),
        });
    });
```

The three textboxes are:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdateofbirth" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdoj" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdol" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
```

UPDATED ASPX CODE:-

```
<tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <label class="control-label" for="dob">Date of Birth</label></td>
        <td>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdateofbirth" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdob" runat="server" CssClass="error-class" ControlToValidate="txtdateofbirth" ErrorMessage="Please select the date of birth" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <label class="control-label" for="subject">Date of Join</label></td>
        <td>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdoj" Wrap="true" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdoj" CssClass="error-class" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdoj" ErrorMessage="Please add the date of joining" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <label class="control-label" for="subject">Date of Leaving</label></td>
        <td>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdol" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What do you want the user experience to be if they try to enter an invalid date?

Comment: @EricHughes: They should get message as `Invalid Date`

Comment: Where do you want to place error messages. In input field of datepickers? Or it does not matter?

Comment: @TienNguyen: I want to show the message right below the textboxes where the Datepicker is added

Comment: FYI - This type of question really goes against the spirit of StackOverflow, which is about creating a useful repository of questions and answers.  All you've really done here is gave a template of your content, stated some requirements, and asked for some code to be written for you.  You didn't try to solve it yourself, or if you did, you didn't show what worked or didn't.  The bounty system isn't there to pay people for doing work you should have attempted yourself.  It's there to draw attention to good questions or reward exceptional answers.  This wasn't a good question to begin with.  -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mandarin6b0/kya3Ltg9/2/)

Validation function

```
var validateData = function () {
    var bday = $('#birthdate').val();
    var jday = $('#joiningdate').val();
    var lday = $('#leavingdate').val();

    if (bday && jday && bday > jday) {return}
    if (bday && lday && bday > lday) {return}
    if (jday && lday && jday > lday) {return}

    return true;
};
```

is called onClose event of datepicker, after what error message can be displayed. Feel free to change error displaying method.

```
    onClose: function () {
        validateData() ? $('#errormsg').hide() : $('#errormsg').show();
    }
```

**Update**

To add some css to error message add class to it like

```
<div id="errormsg" class="error-msg">Invalid date</div>
```

And then you can move `display: none;` to your css

**Update**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mandarin6b0/kya3Ltg9/4/) for required fields

Answer (score 2):

Completed JS Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m8df7L6s/1/)

First up let me assume that you actually meant the following

- Joining date should not be **less than** Birthdate
- Leaving Date should not be **less than** Joining Date and BirthDate

and not the other way around, please correct me if I am wrong.

Now going for the solution, you can achieve this by using jQuery Validation Plugin. Simply add a custom validation function to the plugin and validate the form against it. Please see the sample code

```
<form id="myForm">
    <p>Date Of Birth:
        <input type="text" name="datepicker_dob" id="datepicker_dob" />
    </p>
    <p>Date Of Joining:
        <input type="text" name="datepicker_doj" id="datepicker_doj" />
    </p>
    <p>Date Of Leaving:
        <input type="text" name="datepicker_dol" id="datepicker_dol" />
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="saveButton">Save</button>
</form>
```

Initialize your Datetime picker like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id$=datepicker_dob],[id$=datepicker_doj],[id$=datepicker_dol]" ).datepicker({
       // add this option when you initialise the datetime picker, this will
       // validate date based on our custom validation rule when we select a date 
        onSelect:function(){
            $(this).valid(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Next up is adding a custom validator function

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateValidatorLE", function(value, element, params) {

    var isDateValid = true;
    $(params).each(function(i) {
      //  alert($(params[i]).val());
        isDateValid &= (Date.parse(value) > Date.parse($(params[i]).val()))
    });
    return this.optional(element) || isDateValid;
}, $.validator.format('general error message'));
```

The validate your form

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        datepicker_doj: {
            dateValidatorLE: ['#datepicker_dob']
        },        
        datepicker_dol: {
            dateValidatorLE: ['#datepicker_dob', '#datepicker_doj']
        }
    },
    messages: {
        datepicker_doj: {
            dateValidatorLE: 'DOJ must be greater than DOB'
        },        
        datepicker_dol: {
            dateValidatorLE: 'DOL must be greater that DOJ and DOB'
        }
    },
    onkeyup: function(e) {
      this.element(e);
    }
});
```

Let me know if this is helpful to you.

Comment: Yes,it will be more helpful if it will be in asp.net. As Tien has already done that in HTML. Do let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get how you want your code to look. Anyways, it's a simple validation that you can put in a function if you want :

```
function validateMyForm() {
    return ($('#txtdoj').val() <= $('#txtdateofbirth').val() 
        && $('#txtdol').val() <= $('#txtdateofbirth').val() 
        && $('#txtdol').val() <= $('#txtdoj').val() 
        && $('#txtdol').val() <= $('#txtdateofbirth').val());
}
```

This will return true if the form is valid or false if it's not

Comment: I want simple error message to be shown if user inputs wrong data