# Validation for Birth Date, Joining Date and Leaving Date

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have three textboxes for `BirthDate`, `JoiningDate` & `LeavingDate`.

What I am trying to ensure is:

1. `Joining date` and `Leaving date` should not be greater than `Birthdate`
2. `Leaving Date` should not be greater than `Joining Date` and `BirthDate`.

I would like to throw an error when a wrong entry has been entered.

I have used the DatePicker to get a date input from the user.

Here is the JS code I am using:-

```
$(function () {
    $("[id$=mainContent_txtdateofbirth], [id$=mainContent_txtdoj], [id$=mainContent_txtdol]").datepicker({
        textboxImageOnly: true,
        textboxImage: 'images/calendar.png',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy / mm / dd",
        yearRange: "-40:+0",
        maxDate: new Date(),
    });
});
```

The textboxes code I am using:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdateofbirth" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdoj" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdol" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
```

I got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434096/date-validation-for-birth-date-joining-date-and-leaving-date), but it is not a button click like I am attempting to do.

Here is my related code:-

```
tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <label class="control-label" for="dob">Date of Birth</label></td>
    <td>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtdateofbirth" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdob" runat="server" CssClass="error-class" ControlToValidate="txtdateofbirth" ErrorMessage="Please select the date of birth" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <label class="control-label" for="subject">Date of Join</label></td>
    <td>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtdoj" Wrap="true" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdoj" CssClass="error-class" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdoj" ErrorMessage="Please add the date of joining" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <label class="control-label" for="subject">Date of Leaving</label></td>
    <td>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtdol" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-prm" Text="Submit" Width="75" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="AddNew" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Please suggest how I can validate these dates based on the criteria listed above.

Comment: I don't think your question is well worded, please be more concise in what you are asking. From my understanding you are asking for suggestions on how to determine if `joiningdate` and `leavingdate` are before `birthdate`? Is this correct?

Comment: @Pseudonym: Yes, its correct. Basically I want validations if dates are not entered correctly

Comment: Do you want to determine this client-side or server-side?

Comment: *"Leaving Date should not be greater than Joining Date and BirthDate"* - So you want to ensure that people leave *before* they join and before they are born?

Comment: @Pseudonym: Both will be accepted, I want that error to throw on button click

Comment: @nnnnnn: I mean to say, if they enter leaving date before the Joining date it should throw an error, my mistake for that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some Research from [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/01/end-date-should-not-be-greater-than.html) and wrote the below code:-

```
 $(function () {
      $("[id$=mainContent_txtdateofbirth]").datepicker({
          textboxImageOnly: true,
          textboxImage: 'images/calendar.png',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "dd / mm / yy",
          yearRange: "-40:+0",
          onSelect: function (selected) {
              $("#mainContent_txtdoj").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
              $("#mainContent_txtdol").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
          }
      });
      $("[id$=mainContent_txtdoj]").datepicker({
          textboxImageOnly: true,
          textboxImage: 'images/calendar.png',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "dd / mm / yy",
          yearRange: "-40:+0",
          onSelect: function (selected) {
              $("#mainContent_txtdateofbirth").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
              $("#mainContent_txtdol").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
          }
      });

      $("[id$=mainContent_txtdol]").datepicker({
          textboxImageOnly: true,
          textboxImage: 'images/calendar.png',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "dd / mm / yy",
          yearRange: "-40:+0",
          onSelect: function (selected) {
              $("#mainContent_txtdateofbirth").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
              $("#mainContent_txtdoj").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
          }
      });
  });
```

It's the other way round but it works..!!!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2** From the comments you've posted it seems like it may be more difficult to put all the pieces together than I anticipated so here is what you need to do in order to get the result you want:

1. Wire up an event on the server side for your button click
2. Within that function assign the values of your datepickers to 3 separate variables
3. Using the example code below for C#, compare `leavedate` and `joindate` to `birthdate` and determine if `leavedate` and `joindate` occur before or after `birthdate`
4. Continue with whatever else your application does

**EDIT:** Here is another [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on how to wire up a button click. So if you put all the pieces together you will get your desired result of validating dates on a button click.

Comparing dates, especially in the way you want to is relatively straightforward.

To do it server-side (in C#), here is a [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article and example:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
      DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
      int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
      string relationship;

      if (result < 0)
         relationship = "is earlier than";
      else if (result == 0)
         relationship = "is the same time as";         
      else
         relationship = "is later than";

      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//    8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM is earlier than 8/1/2009 12:00:00 PM
```

To do it client-side (in Javascript), here is a, here is a [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) article and example:

```
var today, someday, text; today = new Date(); someday = new Date(); someday.setFullYear(2100, 0, 14);

if (someday > today) {
    text = "Today is before January 14, 2100."; } else {
    text = "Today is after January 14, 2100."; } document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: It's not related to what I want, I want that to be in asp.net. I want on button click.

Comment: Actually it is very related to your question as asked. The above code shows you how to validate whether a date comes before or after another date using either C# or Javascript. If you also need help on how to do this within a button click I would specify that within your question

Comment: I have mentioned that, i want it on button click

Comment: Added some more information on how to wire up a button click. All the pieces are in my answer I will leave it to you to assemble them into working code

Comment: I know how to write `onClick` of button, But the main part here is validation which I dont have.

Comment: Actually you do, if you wire up the button click, and use code similar to the date validation for C# I have posted then you will have what you are asking for.

Comment: I can understand that..!! I will try

Comment: Posted step by step instructions

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I got the solution anyways :)